# Variável de sessão vazia quando redirecionado

Tags: php, session

Estou usando variáveis de sessão para verificar o usuário logado no site.

Tenho dois links diferentes para a mesma página, um gerado automaticamente por um script PHP através de uma consulta no meu banco de dados. O outro eu mesmo coloquei no site.

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte, quando uso o link gerado pela consulta no banco de dados as variáveis de sessão que tenho definidas mantém todas o seu valor. Mas quando uso o link que eu coloquei na página, todas as variáveis de sessão ficam vazias.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Olá gabriel, sem código não tem como resolver seu problema.

Comment: Está utilizando `session_start();` em todas as páginas?

Comment: Oi Marcelo, coloquei o código resumido embaixo

Comment: Uso `session_start();` em todas as páginas sim

Answer (score -2):

Enfim, consegui resolver meu problema, mas vou deixar as coisas mais bem explicadas aqui para alguém que possa ter o mesmo problema que o meu.

Em uma página do site gero o link para outra pelo seguinte script:

```
<?php
//Verifica as questões do relatório disponíveis no banco de dados
$query = "SELECT idquestao, numquestao FROM questao WHERE relatorio_idrelatorio = '"
        . $_GET['id'] . "' ORDER BY numquestao";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $acessar = "http://www.site.com/questao.php?id=" . $linha['idquestao'];
    echo "<li><a href='" . $acessar . "'>Atividade " . $linha['numquestao'] . "</a></li>";
}
?>
```

E nessa mesma página gero um link para a mesma outra página pelo código:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/questao.php?id=1">Reponder</a>
```

O meu problema era o seguinte, quando usava o link que foi gerado pelo script PHP era redirecionado para a outra página e as minhas variáveis de sessão mantinham os seus valores.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['id'] || !$_SESSION['nome'] || !$_SESSION['usuario']) {
        //header("Location:http://www.site.com/?erro=2");
    }
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
    echo $_SESSION['nome'];
    echo $_SESSION['usuario'];
?>
```

De forma que o código acima exibia os valores passados para as variáveis quando o usuário fez o login.

> 2 Gabriel gabriel

Porém quando usava o link que eu mesmo tinha colocado na página, as variáveis de sessão apareciam vazias.

> 

A forma como o problema se resolveu foi apenas retirando o "www" do início do link

```
<a href="http://site.com/questao.php?id=1">Reponder</a>
```

Dessa forma quando clico no link as variáveis de sessão apresentam os valores corretamente.

> 2 Gabriel gabriel

Não sei o porque desse problema, mas resolvi dessa forma.

Aparentemente o PHP não gosta de "www" rs